# Does it matter how much excess energy per turn you have when activating the Beacon?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

In Civilization: Beyond Earth when doing the Contact victory the Civilopedia says that after spending the 1000 energy to activate the Beacon, all excess energy income is transferred to the Beacon, and then when a "set amount" is transferred you win the game. How much is this "set amount"? When I activated the Beacon I had about 150/turn excess energy, and the victory screen said 30 turns remaining. Then I changed all my worker and production allocations to maximize energy, bringing me up to about 230/turn excess energy (now consumed by the Beacon), and it still said 30 turns remaining (and after moving on to the next turn, 29 turns remaining, just in case it recalculates at the end of the turn.) What is going on here?

Answer (score 7):

It takes 30 turns (on standard) regardless of your income.

Comment: My guess is the reason for the weird wording is that it used to be an amount of energy but was changed when they realized that was unbalanced

Answer (score 2):

Yeh it doesn't matter. I was pumping out between 400-500 energy the entire time and it still took 30 turns.