# Why can't I build the Beacon

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I have discovered the two Progenitor Signals and Decoded them. The Beacon appears in the build list and isn't greyed out. When I click to select it though all of the worker assignments in the city screen turn blank and the Beacon doesn't move to the Production queue.

I thought it may have been because I had 3 unemployed citizens so reset Citizen Management but that didn't help.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Beacon, like all planetary Wonders, must be constructed on a separate tile which you select by clicking the assignment circle above the desired tile in the city screen.

[image: placing the Emancipation Gate wonder]

*<sup>Pictured is the Emancipation Gate wonder placement, but it operates similarly to the Beacon</sup>*

If the tile contains a preexisting improvement, the improvement will be removed.

Once construction of the Beacon has completed, you must activate it by selecting it and clicking the (what I found to be a bit subtle) activation button from the unit action menu. Doing so will require 1000 available Energy and will consume all excess Energy for a number of turns, the amount of excess [having no impact](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189556/does-it-matter-how-much-excess-energy-per-turn-you-have-when-activating-the-beac?rq=1) on the completion time.

[image: Beacon activation button]

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't experienced the need to select a site for a wonder previously. All the other wonders I built were automatically in the active city. Maybe it only applies to **Victory Wonders**? BTW this is on my first play through so experience is "limited" ATM.

Comment: "Planetary Wonders" are a different type of wonder to normal wonders. They take up a hex, and they are usually related to Victory conditions.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Yeah, it's a special feature of planetary wonders, as Michael mentions in his comment. They each have special conditions as they apply to victory for (presumably) balancing purposes, although the wonder for the "Promised Land" victory is *particularly* involved, which is something to keep in mind before attempting that path.